# ZF2 Form Bind with Model

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2

I am trying out the book "Zend Framework 2.0 by Example". I am working on editing the profile; where we have the table with

```
user_id
user_first_name
User_middle_name
user_last_name
user_email
user_password
user_password_seed
user_status_code
user_role_code
```

the form has the following fields

```
user_id - hidden
user_first_name
User_middle_name
user_last_name
user_email
```

I have the action controller code as follows

```
$this->viewModel = new ViewModel ( );
$request = $this->getRequest ( );
$form = $this->getServiceLocator ( )->get ( 'ModifyUserForm' );
$userTable = $this->getServiceLocator ( )->get ( 'UserTable' );
$user_id = $this->params ( )->fromRoute ( 'id' );
$user = $userTable->getUser ( $user_id );
$before = $userTable->getUser ( $user_id );
$this->viewModel->post = $request->getPost( );
$this->viewModel->beforebinduser = $before;
$form->bind ( $user );
$form->setData ( $request->getPost ( ) );
$this->viewModel->afterbinduser = $user;

#$form->setValidationGroup( 'user_first_name', 'user_middle_name', 'user_last_name', 'user_email' );
if ( $form->isValid ( ) ) {
    $userTable->saveUser ( $user );
    $this->viewModel->aftersaveuser = $user;
}
```

The problem I have is that all the columns that are not in the form are replaced with null; 
I have searched the web the whole day for this and still not solved.

code for saveuser in the model

```
 public function saveUser ( User $user ) {

        $data = array (
            'user_id' => $user->user_id,
            'user_email' => $user->user_email,
            'user_first_name' => $user->user_first_name,
            'user_middle_name' => $user->user_middle_name,
            'user_last_name' => $user->user_last_name,
            'user_status_code' => $user->user_status_code,
            'user_password' => $user->user_password,
            'user_password_seed' => $user->user_password_seed,
            'user_login_enabled_flag' => $user->user_login_enabled_flag,
            'user_role_code' => $user->user_role_code,
            'create_userid' => $user->create_userid,
            'create_timestamp' => $user->create_timestamp,
            'last_update_userid' => $user->last_update_userid,
            'last_update_timestamp' => $user->last_update_timestamp,
        );

        $user_id = ( int ) $user->user_id;
        #need to set the correct last update userid
        $data [ 'last_update_userid' ] = 1;
        $data [ 'last_update_timestamp' ] = date ( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
        if ( $user_id === 0 ) {
            #need to set the correct create userid
            $data [ 'user_status_code' ] = "ACTIVE";
            $data [ 'user_role_code' ] = "ADMIN";
            $data [ 'user_login_enabled_flag' ] = "Y";
            $data [ 'create_userid' ] = 1;
            $data [ 'create_timestamp' ] = date ( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
            $this->tableGateway->insert( $data );
        } else {
            if ( $this->getUser ( $user_id ) ) {
                if ( empty( $data[ 'user_password' ] ) ) {
                    unset( $data[ 'user_password' ] );
                }
                $this->tableGateway->update( $data, array ( 'user_id' => $user_id ) );
            } else {
            throw new \Exception ( "Could not find row in table $this->table with $user_id for update" );
            }
        }

    }
```

Thank in advance for the help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

crate a [NullObject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) and set a [Hydrator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.stdlib.hydrator.html) to your form.

The Hydrator will be hydrate the given Data (from your Request) to your NullObject

```
<?php
/* other stuff */
$form->setHydrator(\Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods); /* <--- this line to set zf2 ClassMethods Hydrator */
$form->bind($user); /* $user should be the NullObject */
$form->setData($request->getPost());
$this->viewModel->afterbinduser = $user;

#$form->setValidationGroup( 'user_first_name', 'user_middle_name', 'user_last_name', 'user_email' );
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $userTable->saveUser($user);
    $this->viewModel->aftersaveuser = $user;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I searched again and found
something similar
I used "$form->setHydrator( new \Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\Reflection( ) )"
and it worked. I am going to read up on this...